# send image from php to flash

Tags: actionscript-3

I have populated a php page where i pull image in that php. Now how can i put those image in flash by array. The php code is

```
<?PHP

$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbname");

$query = "SELECT * FROM dress where dress_type='shirts' AND sex='male'";
$results = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
            { 
              $path = $row["imagelocation"];
              $final = "<img src='$path' width='100' height='100'>\n";
              echo "$final";
 }



mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$path = $row["imagelocation"];
$final = "<img src='$path' width='100' height='100'>\n";
echo "$final";
```

To this:

```
$path = $row["imagelocation"];
echo $path . "#";
```

This way you get a Hash delimited list of all your image paths.

Then when you load that PHP document you'll be able to create an array of all your image paths:

```
var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader(
    new URLRequest("your_php_file.php")
);

ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _done);
function _done(e:Event):void
{
    ldr.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _done);

    var ar:Array = String(e.target.data).split("#");

    for each(var i:String in ar)
    {
        var img:Loader = new Loader();
        img.load(new URLRequest(i));

        addChild(img);
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not work for me. I also have to show images in flahs. Can you help me?

Comment: The code that I have should show the images - you need to replace `your_php_file.php` with the URL to your PHP script.

Comment: It works to show me images. But the images is overlaping. What should i do?

Comment: Move each of the images to where you need them to be by manipulating their `x` and `y` properties.

Comment: I am new in flash world. Can you tell me how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Basically in the part where I've created `img:Loader` you'll be able to say `img.x = 200;` and so on.

Comment: It works. But it place the all image. How to move the images one after another?

Comment: This is not the right forum for what seems to be a very basic flash tutorial. You should probably read one or more online tutorials on the subject :)

Comment: @ M. Wallace i have tryed your code. In your code you use for each loop to show images. Now if i want to show the image as you take the path of the image in an ARRAY than what should i do?